# ThreeJS: How to return the direction left/right for a object3D to other vector3

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions

I simple want to determine if the path goes left or right if the angle is wide enough.

I tried to apply the rotation or quaternion to face starting Vector3 in the right direction. But im probably using it wrong...

```
if (nextPoint) {
   let tempObject = new THREE.Object3D()
   tempObject.position.set(point.x, point.y, point.z)
   tempObject.lookAt(nextPoint);
   // tempObject.updateMatrix();
   tempObject.updateMatrixWorld(); 
   let dirVec = new THREE.Vector3(point.x, point.y, point.z);
   dirVec.applyQuaternion(tempObject.quaternion);
   dirVec.applyMatrix4(tempObject.matrix);

   // Gives me strange outcomes, I expect a positive or negative number around 90 or -90 degrees
   console.log(
      dirVec.angleTo(nextPoint), 
      radiansToDegrees(dirVec.angleTo(nextPoint))
   )
}
```

Code above is from my repo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-snowflake-4trvuq?file=/src/index.js

What I expect
Is some way to get an positive or negative angle in 3D space if the path goes left or right. The angle should be wide enough to determine that.

Comment: what outcome you obtain and what outcome you expect?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay thanks for the reply. As stated I want to determine if the path goes left or right if the angle is wide enough. If not clear I am making walking directions on a map and want to generate some automated turns. tx